# Lazy loading effect for RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Android Studio 2.3.3.

I have Fragment that shows list items. I use component **android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView**  to show list. OK. It's work fine.

Now I need to do lazy loading of items (scrolling vertically):

1. reached the **top** of the list
2. reached the **bottom** of the list

Here example:

[image: Example of lazy loading]

Is it possible by **RecyclerView** or I need to use another component or library?

Comment: use `RecyclerView` and google's [paging](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging.html) library

Comment: Try this tutorial for pagination https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Endless-Scrolling-with-AdapterViews-and-RecyclerView

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty simple:

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            if (!recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1) && isMoreDataAvailable && !isLoading) {
                isLoading = true;
                pb_loading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                PrepareData(ppage,pcount);
            }
        }
    });
```

**isLoading** is for when control user not to send many other requests at loading time and **isMoreDataAvailable** is for avoiding more requests when there is no more data.

Comment: pb_loading is probably the only important information and you didn't explained what it is

Comment: @E.Akio its a progress bar. Why do you think an item which you just change the visibility is the most important information

Comment: That is basically the main component author wants to display with your logic